How to get the jwt string back from HttpContext.User
I am wiring up some new jwt authentication logic my asp.net core application.
I have something like
service
   .AddAuthentication(...)
   .AddJwtBearer(opts =>
       {
          opts.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
          {
             ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
             ValidateActor = false,
             ValidateAudience = true,
             ValidIssuer = "myissuer.com",
             ValidAudience = "clientId",
             ValidateLifetime = true,
             ValidTypes = new List<string> { "JWT" },
             AuthenticationType = "myCustomJwtAuthType"
          };
       });

Which successfully creates set the HttpContext.User ClaimsPrincipal object up for me. What I was wondering how to do, was how to get back the original bearer token string that was passed on the Authorization header, from the HttpContext.User?

Is it possible?
If possible, why should I not be doing this?


Why not just pull it out of the Authorization header?

"If possible, why should I not be doing this?" - A better question is: why do you want to? It's not clear why you're trying to do this, and it seems likely that there will be a better way.

The advantage of HttpContext.User is that it's not tied to any specific authentication method, you don't need to worry about working with cookies or tokens, the framework will take care of it for you and gives you ClaimsPrincipal. In any case that you need to go deep and access a raw cookie or token, then just get it from HTTP headers.

Well I want it so it can be used to call other downstream apis. I could just get it from the header... I think why I'm confused is I don't understand how I get into a situation where an API call has multiple ClaimIdentities on the principal. I was thinking that if I have multiple identities on my principal, where and how should I get the jwt back from the identity it was from? If I actually understand how to use multiple claim identities, this problem may go away.
